# Driver for Sound card

Tags: drivers, sound

I have the following sound card, however in settings for sound it shows Dummy Output so it is not recognized. How do I get this driver? I am using Logitech S120 external speakers on a mini PC w/ Ubuntu v. 22.04

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 4dc8 (rev 01)

```
DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 131
Memory at 6002120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 6002000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: access denied
Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-icl
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_icl
```